# Rf_error and Rf_warning definitions

Tags: r

Where can I find the definitions for these two functions. Grepping for their name brings only declarations but I can't find their implementation in the source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably you are looking for the C code function definitions.  What I typically do when looking for the definitions is search across all files for the function name without the `Rf_` but with the return type.  For example, for `Rf_error`, I would search for `void error`.  In this case you pretty quickly get (from src/main/errors.c@758, for R version 3.2.2):

```
void error(const char *format, ...)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    RCNTXT *c = R_GlobalContext;

    va_list(ap);
    va_start(ap, format);
    Rvsnprintf(buf, min(BUFSIZE, R_WarnLength), format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    /* This can be called before R_GlobalContext is defined, so... */
    /* If profiling is on, this can be a CTXT_BUILTIN */
    if (c && (c->callflag & CTXT_BUILTIN)) c = c->nextcontext;
    errorcall(c ? c->call : R_NilValue, "%s", buf);
}
```

`Rf_warning` is defined at line 262 of the same file.

Answer (score 6):

Note the following lines in `src/include/R_ext/Error.h`

```
#ifndef R_NO_REMAP
#define error Rf_error
#define warning Rf_warning
#endif
```

`R_NO_REMAP` is usually not defined, so that means the macro `error` expands to `Rf_error`. So, in files that include `Error.h`, instances of `error` will be replaced with `Rf_error` by the preprocessor.

So you need to search for the function with the same return type and arguments. As BrodieG notes in his answer, the functions also usually (always?) have the same name, but without the `Rf_` prefix.

Thanks to Duncan Murdoch for helpful pointers. Any errors are mine.

Comment: Thanks Joshua.  I knew I had seen this type of code elsewhere about the Rf_ remap, but gave up trying to find it after a couple of minutes.